# I need to make a Google form available for a specific time each day

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

We have a Google form that we would only like to be made available to users at a specific time each day.  It should only be open from 2:00 to 2:15, Monday thru Friday.  Wasn't sure if the following would work:

```
FORM_OPEN_DATE   = 
FORM_CLOSE_DATE  =
```

Not exactly sure of the value to place after the = sign.  Looked the JavaScript Date objects but could not find a one that I thought would work.

Comment: You have to check the current date/time in the initialize script.  There is no in-built method for doing this.

Answer (score -2):

There is no built-in functionality to do that. In order to do that you can go with [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: link only answers are of little value here. A link to javascript date docs doesn't answer the question either. Show how it would solve the problem

Comment: I have created the following script.  Not sure if this is going to work                                                function myFunction() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth();
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var hr = today.getHours();
  var mn = today.getMinutes();
  today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
  today2 = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy+' '+hr:mn;

  FORMOPENDATE   =  "today 14:00";
  FORMCLOSEDATE  =  "today 14:15";
  
  IF today2 < FORMOPENDATE and today2 > FORMCLOSEDATE
  
  CloseForm();
}